# What is the equivalent Javascript request header for this CURL script?

Tags: javascript, curl, titanium

I'm trying to communicate with this webservice using javascript how do I set the last requestheader using javascript?

```
curl -X POST \
      -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: 57865" \
      -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: 87468977" \
      -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
      -d '{}' \
    http://api.thisisatest.com/1/test
```

so far i have this below, but the "d" is incorrect and I'm not sure what that should be any help is appreciated.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-Application-Id",  "57865");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Parse-REST-API-Key", "87468977");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
//xhr.setRequestHeader("d", "{}");
```

Comment: `-d` is data. It isn't a header. That's typically what you would POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-d` represent the actual request body. Try this:

```
xhr.send('{}');
```